# Why query mysql 8.0 response too slow with respect to mysql 5.5

Tags: performance, optimization, mysql-5.5, mysql-8.0, query-performance

I have the following query which in mysql 5.5, original server runs in approximately 3 seconds but all the opposite with respect to mysql 8.0, which runs in about 3 minutes, a big difference!!!. This is the query:

```
SELECT
`f`.`idFactura` AS `idFactura`,
`f`.`idCliente` AS `idCliente`,
`f`.`folio` AS `folio`,
`f`.`empresa` AS `empresa`,
`f`.`fecha` AS `fecha`,
`f`.`fechaInicio` AS `fechaInicio`,
`f`.`fechaFin` AS `fechaFin`,
`f`.`fechaVencimiento` AS `fechaVencimiento`,
`f`.`saldoAnterior` AS `saldoAnterior`,
`f`.`username` AS `username`,
`f`.`baja` AS `baja`,
`f`.`intento` AS `intento`,
( SELECT sum( `pagos`.`importe` ) FROM `pagos` WHERE ( `pagos`.`idFactura` = `f`.`idFactura` ) ) AS `pagosF`,
( SELECT ( `f`.`saldoAnterior` - COALESCE ( `pagosF`, 0 ) ) ) AS `saldoPendiente`,
(
SELECT
sum( ( `c`.`precio` * `c`.`cantidad` ) )
FROM
`contenidoFacturas` `c`
WHERE
( ( `c`.`idOriginal` = 0 ) AND ( `c`.`idFactura` = `f`.`idFactura` ) )
) AS `totalOriginal`,
(
SELECT
sum( `c`.`cantidad` )
FROM
`contenidoFacturas` `c`
WHERE
( ( `c`.`idOriginal` = 0 ) AND ( `c`.`idFactura` = `f`.`idFactura` ) )
) AS `cantidadOriginal`,
(
SELECT
sum( ( `c`.`precio` * `c`.`cantidad` ) )
FROM
`contenidoFacturas` `c`
WHERE
( ( `c`.`editada` = 0 ) AND ( `c`.`idFactura` = `f`.`idFactura` ) )
) AS `total`,
(
SELECT
sum( `c`.`cantidad` )
FROM
`contenidoFacturas` `c`
WHERE
( ( `c`.`editada` = 0 ) AND ( `c`.`idFactura` = `f`.`idFactura` ) )
) AS `cantidad`,
( SELECT ( `f`.`total` + COALESCE ( `saldoPendiente`, 0 ) ) ) AS `totalPagar`,
`f`.`aprobada` AS `aprobada`,
`f`.`enviada` AS `enviada`,
`f`.`tiempoEnvioSicsa` AS `tiempoEnvioSicsa`,
`f`.`uuid` AS `uuid`,
`f`.`observaciones` AS `observaciones`,
`f`.`fechaEnvio` AS `fechaEnvio`,
`f`.`esNota` AS `esNota`,
`f`.`level` AS `level`,
`f`.`moneda` AS `moneda`,
`f`.`tipoCambio` AS `tipoCambio`
FROM
`facturas` `f`
```

***Execution plan from MySQL server 5.5***

```
`<table>`+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                | rows  | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | f     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL               | 15302 |             |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    15 | Using where |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    15 | Using where |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    15 | Using where |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    15 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pagos | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |  5268 |             |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+-------+-------------+`</table>`
6 rows in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Execution plan from MySQL server 8.0

```
`<table>`+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref                | rows  | filtered | Extra          |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | f     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL               | 15411 |   100.00 | NULL           |
|  8 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL               |  NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
|  7 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | NULL       | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    33 |    10.00 | Using where    |
|  6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | NULL       | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    33 |    10.00 | Using where    |
|  5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | NULL       | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    33 |    10.00 | Using where    |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c     | NULL       | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura |    33 |    10.00 | Using where    |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | NULL  | NULL       | NULL | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    | NULL               |  NULL |     NULL | No tables used |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | pagos | NULL       | ref  | idFactura     | idFactura | 4       | ipbell.f.idFactura | 10474 |   100.00 | NULL           |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+-------+----------+----------------+`</table>`
8 rows in set, 10 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

What is the reason of this big difference?, we are trying the new version

Running SHOW INDEX FROM pagos can I advertise the cardinality from idFactura key is too slow

```
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| pagos |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | idPago      | A         |       10474 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| ***pagos |          1 | idFactura |            1 | idFactura   | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |***
| pagos |          1 | shortName |            1 | shortName   | A         |         246 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| pagos |          1 | fecha     |            1 | fecha       | A         |        1000 |     NULL |   NULL | YES  | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+-------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Please do not use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) here. Paste in (formatted) text.

Comment: Adding a index hint LIKE FORCE INDEX in pagos table improved substantially the execution from the query passing 3 minutes to 4 seconds but the question is why i have to use an index hint to improve the performance of the query?

Comment: Please format your text when you paste in large amounts of it - there are  widgets above the edit box - it's the fifth from the left `{}`. Also, maybe you should put the `FORCE INDEX` in the title of your question? Also, please remove the screenshots and replace them with text!